# API resolved without sending a response, this may result in stalled requests while using multer and next connect for uploading file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

API is working fine but I'm getting this error in console.
API resolved without sending a response for, this may result in stalled requests.
I'm using multer and next-connect in next.js for file uploading, which is working great but I'm getting above error as well
Here is my Code

```
import db from "@/backend/config/db";
import Categories from "@/backend/model/category";
import { createRouter } from "next-connect";
import multer from "multer";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false, // Disallow body parsing, consume as stream
  },
};
db().catch(() => res.status(405).json({ error: "Error in the Connection" }));
const router = createRouter();

const options = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./public/assets/images/categories",
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      // const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + "-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
      // cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + uniqueSuffix);
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
  }),

  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype.match(/\/(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(res.status(400).json({ error: "image type is not supported" }));
    }
  },
});

const uploadCategoryImage = options.single("image");

router.use(uploadCategoryImage).post(async (req, res) => {
  await Categories.create({ ...req.body, image: req.file.filename }).then(
    (data) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        code: 200,
        status: "Success!",
        message: "category created successfully",
        data: data,
      });
    }
  );
});

export default router.handler({
  onError(error, req, res) {
    res
      .status(501)
      .json({ error: `Sorry something Happened! ${error.message}` });
  },
  onNoMatch(req, res) {
    res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
  },
});
```

please Suggest me good answer

Answer (score 0):

try to replace your code

```js
//...
router.use(uploadCategoryImage).post(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await db();
    const data = await Categories.create({
      ...req.body,
      image: req.file.filename,
    });
    res.status(200).json({
      code: 200,
      status: "Success!",
      message: "category created successfully",
      data: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(501).json({
      error: `Sorry something Happened! ${error.message}`,
    });
  }
});

//...
```

I have added a try-catch block around the Categories.create() call to catch any errors that may occur. I have also awaited the db() function call before executing the database query.